# Which preposition is to be used with verb 'diagnose' ... something?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, prepositional-verbs

Which preposition is correct?

- She was **diagnosed of** placenta previa.

or

- She was **diagnosed with** placenta previa.

Comment: Diagnosed with.

Comment: *diagnosed **as having** placenta previa*

Comment: Or none: The consultant diagnosed placenta previa.

Comment: @WeatherVane Unless the consultant is a medical consultant or a doctor capable of diagnosing diseases, I think you need a copula there. "_The consultant **was** diagnosed placenta previa._"

Comment: @EddieKal I did mean where the consultant is a medical practitioner, and was able to diagnose the presence of the condition in a patient. I don't understand the meaning of your quoted sentence.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think the OP's constructed sentences both assume the subject to be the patient--in both grammatical and literal senses: a semantic role that is on the receiving end of the action "diagnose" as well as the patient being diagnosed. So I thought your example also had "the consultant" in the same role and was meant to demonstrate that "diagnose" could also be used in an active construct with the patient as the subject, with which I disagree. That's why in my modified version I inserted the "was". But now that you've clarified, it seems we are on the same page.

Comment: @EddieKal yes, I was focused on the object.

Comment: Unless the consultant is a medical consultant or a doctor capable of diagnosing diseases, I think you need a copula there. "The consultant was diagnosed placenta previa. – @Eddie Ka

You mean that I have to mention the subject who is the Doctor and no need for passive ??

Comment: @RihamAchraf I did not mean that at all. The consultant is not the patient, but the person making the diagnosis. It was an example that does not use a preposition.